# Transition hamburger / menu icon into cross /close icon using only CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to use a hack to change the "ham menu" icon to "close" icon on click using pure CSS only. Please check the code:

```css
.ham
{
 height: 30px;
 padding: 15px 20px;
}
.dsp-none
{
  display:none;
}
.cross
{
  display:none;
  height: 30px;
 padding: 15px 20px; 
}
.ham-icon:checked .cross
{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="click" type="checkbox" name="menu" class="ham-icon dsp-none"/><label for="click" class="ham-lnk"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve" class="ham tr-fl"><rect x="12" y="20" width="40" height="2"/><rect x="12" y="32" width="40" height="2"/><rect x="12" y="44" width="40" height="2"/></svg>
            <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             width="611.979px" height="611.979px" viewBox="0 0 611.979 611.979" class="cross"><g><path d="M356.781,305.982L601.453,61.311c14.033-14.033,14.033-36.771,0-50.774c-14.004-14.033-36.741-14.033-50.774,0
              L306.007,255.208L61.277,10.536c-14.004-14.033-36.771-14.033-50.774,0c-14.004,14.004-14.004,36.742,0,50.774l244.701,244.672
              L10.503,550.684c-14.004,14.004-14.004,36.771,0,50.774c7.016,7.017,16.216,10.51,25.387,10.51c9.2,0,18.371-3.493,25.387-10.51
              l244.701-244.701l244.671,244.701c7.017,7.017,16.217,10.51,25.388,10.51c9.199,0,18.399-3.493,25.387-10.51
              c14.033-14.033,14.033-36.771,0-50.774L356.781,305.982z"/></g></svg></label>
```

I am not able to get the desired result.
On click, it should change to cross icon. No animation or transitions to use. Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you are using an SVG for that, you can do it just with a bit of HTML and some CSS.

There's a comment in the example's CSS:

```
/* Try different values here: .25rem, .5rem, .2rem, 5rem, 10rem... */
transform-origin: 5rem center;
```

I personally like how the effect looks with `5rem`, but you might prefer something between `.25rem` to `2rem`.

Here's the code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const icon =  document.getElementById('icon');

button.onclick = () => icon.classList.toggle('close');
```

```css
#button {
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 100, 100);
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

/* MENU ICON */

.lines,
.lines:before,
.lines:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.lines {
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  top: 50%;
}

.lines:before,
.lines:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;

  /* Try different values here: .25rem, .5rem, .2rem, 5rem, 10rem... */
  transform-origin: 5rem center;
}

.lines:before {
  top: 8px;
}

.lines:after {
  top: -8px;
}

/* CLOSE ICON */

.close {
  transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}

.close .lines {
 background: transparent;
}

.close .lines:before,
.close .lines:after {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.close .lines:before {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}

.close .lines:after {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <div id="icon">
    <span class="lines"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, if you just need to fix yours, the main problem is that the CSS selectors (or the HTML structure) are wrong. For example, you have this selector:

```
.ham-icon:checked .cross
```

But in your original HTML `.cross` is not a descendant of `.ham-icon`.

I changed a bit the structure of the HTML, the CSS selectors and adjusted a bit the cross icon SVG:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* DEFULT: Menu icon shown, close icon hidden */

#menu-icon {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

#close-icon {
  display:none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px; 
}

/* CHECKED: Menu icon hidden, close icon shown */

#checkbox:checked + #menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

#checkbox:checked ~ #close-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>

  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="menu" class="hidden"/>

  <svg id="menu-icon"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 64 64"
    enable-background="new 0 0 64 64"
    xml:space="preserve">
    
    <rect x="12" y="20" width="40" height="2"/>
    <rect x="12" y="32" width="40" height="2"/>
    <rect x="12" y="44" width="40" height="2"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="close-icon"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="-100 -100 800 800">
  
    <g><path d="M356.781,305.982L601.453,61.311c14.033-14.033,14.033-36.771,0-50.774c-14.004-14.033-36.741-14.033-50.774,0L306.007,255.208L61.277,10.536c-14.004-14.033-36.771-14.033-50.774,0c-14.004,14.004-14.004,36.742,0,50.774l244.701,244.672L10.503,550.684c-14.004,14.004-14.004,36.771,0,50.774c7.016,7.017,16.216,10.51,25.387,10.51c9.2,0,18.371-3.493,25.387-10.51l244.701-244.701l244.671,244.701c7.017,7.017,16.217,10.51,25.388,10.51c9.199,0,18.399-3.493,25.387-10.51
c14.033-14.033,14.033-36.771,0-50.774L356.781,305.982z"/></g>
</svg>
              
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, as I mentioned I have to achieve the desired result using CSS and HTML only. NO other scripts to be used. I have these two SVGs only using which I have to attain the result.

Comment: @AKNair Please, check the edit. That might be closer to what you are looking for, although the SVGs probably need further adjustments to look good.

Comment: Thanks alot!!! This was an excellent answer. This works for me.... Also I get to know about the mistake I made.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a example like this on W3Schools. Instead of changing the icon / using *display:none* property use Animations.

Here is the [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js) example

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I checked all these examples. The main problem was to resolve the issue using the existing resources only, which was to complete it by images only. I mentioned that in my question itself that no transitions or animations to be used. I'm not sure why this kind of restriction was given to me, but just because of short timelines, I thought to seek advice here.